# Subset / filter rows of a data.frame by non-standard formatted date

Tags: r, datetime, date-formatting

I have a hourly data.frame `Data` with a `$date` column from years 2015 to 2021. The dates are in `"%d%m%Y HH:MM"` format.

I need to remove specific rows with a certain date, e.g. remove all rows with date "01/09/2021".

I tried this:

```r
Data <- Data[as.Date(format(Data$date, "%d%m%Y")) != 01/09/2021, ]
```

but this didn´t work. What's the correct way to do it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date-time conversion codes are listed in `?strptime`.

`as.Date` returns a string of type "2021-09-01" and class `Date` (see `?Dates` for details), so this would be the correct logic:

```r
Data <- data.frame(id = 1:2, date = c("01012021 00:00","01092021 00:00"))
Data
#>   id           date
#> 1  1 01012021 00:00
#> 2  2 01092021 00:00

Data[as.Date(Data$date, format = "%d%m%Y") != "2021-09-01", ]
#>   id           date
#> 1  1 01012021 00:00
```

Note that strings such as `"01/09/2021"` or `"2021-09-01"` *have* to be quoted in R.

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex approach to remove rows that start with `'01092021'`.

Using data from @scrameri

```
result <- subset(Data, !grepl('^01092021', date))
result

#  id           date
#1  1 01012021 00:00
```